# testing validity of negative solutions to equations with logartihms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am attempting to solve the following equation:

$$
2\log_2x - 1 = \log_2(x + 12)\\                                                                                                                                                
2\log_2x - \log_2(x + 12) = 1\\                                                                                                                                                
\log_2 x^2 - \log_2(x + 12) = 1\\                                                                                                                                              
\log_2 \left(\frac{x^2}{x + 12}\right) = 1\\                                                                                                                                              
2^1 = \frac{x^2}{x + 12}\\                                                                                                                                                     
2(x + 12) = x^2\\                                                                                                                                                              
2x + 24 = x^2\\                                                                                                                                                                
0 = x^2 - 2x - 24\\                                                                                                                                                          
0 = (x - 6)(x + 4)  
$$

Is $-4$ a valid solution?

$$
2\log_2(-4) - 1 = \log_2(-4 + 12)\\ 
$$

Answer (score 1):

$-4$ is not a valid solution, because the logaritmic function is not defined for negative numbers.
In fact, suppose $-4$ is a valid solution and write $log_{2}(-4)=x\Rightarrow 2^{x}=-4$. That is a contradiction, because there is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $2^{x}<0$